# PHP select query returning false

Tags: php, sql, return

I am having this piece of code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con , 'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE group = "'.$_POST['group'].'" ORDER BY date '.$_POST['order'].'');
```

I don't understand why it is always returning me false. The variables $_POST['group'] and $_POST['order'] aren't empty .

```
$_POST['group']='PHP'
$_POST['order']='DESC'
```

The conecction to the database is corect too.

Comment: Add an `echo mysqli_error()` ... and never ever use unsecure POST variables directly in your SQL statement.

Comment: what did you mean by : "Ads an echo mysqli_error()"

Comment: This: `ORDER BY date` could be the issue. Try: `ORDER BY 'date'`.

Comment: @Montoolivo Sorry; **add** `echo mysqli_error();` after your query. It will output the error message from your failed MySQL statement.

Comment: Here is the error message:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group = "All" ORDER BY date ASC' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP` is a [mysql reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be quoted using backticks;

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `group` =  ...
```

You're also wide open to SQL injection, you should never add un-validated/un-escaped POST data in string format to your SQL. The safest way to do queries with user data is using prepared statements, or - as a less secure alternative - escape the data using `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: It's SO easy to forget about those damn reserved words! :)

Comment: I changed group to groups and it worked. I knew group was a keyword but PHP My Admin didn't gave me an error when I named the column of the table like that. Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score -1):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con , "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE group = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['group'])."' ORDER BY date '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['order'])."'";
```

Try formatting the query like this and see if it helps your result. I also added `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to escape your input, as your query was wide open to SQL injection.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: You will end with your order value between single quotes `... ORDER BY date 'DESC'`

Comment: So why didn't you just comment that and give me the opportunity to fix,  instead of down voting?

Comment: And in fact, you just didn't fix the bug by not pointed out the `group` reserved keyword problem...

Comment: @FabienTheSolution You should read this : stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing." – Sound familiar?...

Comment: The fact is that you didn't fix the problem and create a new one...`Use your downvotes whenever you encounter [...] an answer that is clearly [...] incorrect`...and instead of fixing it...you still debate the downvote...